# Where does /etc/profile file in Debian come from?

Tags: debian, profile, etc

Does it belong to some package or is it generated on install time? It looks like [it isn't contained in any packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=/etc/profile).

Comment: See also: [Which Debian package does /etc/environment come from?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85689/9041)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the post installation script of package `base-files` (i.e. `/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst`) it is copied from `/usr/share/base-files/profile`.