# Which Debian package does /etc/environment come from?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, etc

I know that [`/etc/profile` is installed by `base-files`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20990/9041), but it doesn't look like this package installs `/etc/environment`:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/environment
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/environment
```

Which package installs it, and how would I revert it to the package's default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my system (Linux Mint Debian Edition) it seems to come from `libpam-modules`. To find this I first `grep` for `/etc/environment` in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`:

```
grep -C 5 "/etc/environment" /var/lib/dpkg/info/*
```

This shows that the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam-modules:amd64.postinst` contains these lines:

```
if dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt 0.99.9.0-1 && ! [ -f /etc/environment ]
then
    touch /etc/environment
fi
```

This will cause an empty (simple `touch`) `/etc/environment` file to be created if it doesn't exist and if the version of whatever is given to the script as its second argument (`$2`) is less than `0.99.9.0-1`.

Comment: And the reason `libpam-modules` creates `/etc/environment` is [bug #442049](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=442049), because the `pam_env` module writes a log entry each time it fails to find the file. Since an empty file is otherwise effectively equivalent to a non-existent file, the package containing `pam_env` creates the file. But `/etc/environment` isn't owned by that package, it's one of a few configuration files that aren't owned by any package.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Debian's online package search](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents) to do the same thing, which may provide a different result if you haven't updated your local package cache in a while.

That said, it looks like [no package in stable provides `/etc/environment`](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=environment&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any), and searching through oldstable (squeeze) yields the same result.

If it helps, on my system (and I don't recall making any adjustments to that file), it exists but is empty, plain and simple. 0 bytes, mode 0644, mtime 2010-03-27 17:08:01 UTC and no birthtime (because ext3 doesn't do file birthtimes).